# Adding row by row in GridView in runtime

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I am new in C#.I want to add rows in a GridView in runtime. I collect a data from 2 or 3 tables. But whenever I am going to 
bind() it with GridView, the last inserted row is overwritten by current one. And GridView shows only the current row.
Is it possible to show both rows one bellow the other? Or Is there any code for doing so.Please suggest me code for that so that i can use it in my project.Thanks.

Answer::First you have to declare a static datatable.And a boolean variable having value initially "true".
And then execute following code--->>>
Here is My code::

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int coursemasterid = Convert.ToInt32(dlAdmissionCourses.SelectedItem.Value);
    int batchmasterid = Convert.ToInt32(dlAssignBatch.SelectedItem.Value);


    string SQL1 = "SELECT coursename,coursefees,batchname FROM  CourseMaster,BatchMaster WHERE CourseMaster.coursemasterid=BatchMaster.coursemasterid and CourseMaster.coursemasterid="+coursemasterid+" and BatchMaster.batchmasterid="+batchmasterid+"";
      DataTable otable = new DataTable();
        otable = DbHelper.ExecuteTable(DbHelper.CONSTRING, CommandType.Text, SQL1, null);
        DataRow dr1 = otable.Rows[0];
        string coursename = dr1["coursename"].ToString();
        int coursefees = Convert.ToInt32(dr1["coursefees"]);
        string batchname = dr1["batchname"].ToString();

if (chkadd == true)
        {
            dtglb = new DataTable();  //here dtglb is a global datatable
            dtglb.Columns.Add("coursename", typeof(string));
            dtglb.Columns.Add("coursefees", typeof(int));
            dtglb.Columns.Add("batchname", typeof(string));

        }
        foreach (DataRow dr in otable.Rows)
        {
            dtglb.NewRow();
            dtglb.Rows.Add(coursename,coursefees,batchname);

        }
        chkadd = false;
        GridView1.DataSource = dtglb;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

}

Comment: select data from the required tables in a select statement or select data separately from the tables and merge all the results in to a single list and bind it to the grid

Comment: How are you doing it now .. need to see the code

Comment: @V4Vendetta::Thanks for your help.Here I am giving my code.

Comment: @Mahesh::Is it possible in my code to access individual element and them merge multiple rows? if yes,then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  //declaring a datatable global in form 
        DataTable dtglb=new DataTable();

        //In click event    
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=EMS;User ID=sa;Password=sa123");

    string SQL1 = "SELECT coursename,coursefees,batchname FROM  CourseMaster,BatchMaster WHERE CourseMaster.coursemasterid=BatchMaster.coursemasterid and CourseMaster.coursemasterid="+coursemasterid+" and BatchMaster.batchmasterid="+batchmasterid+"";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL1, con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable ds = new DataTable();
    //DataColumn faculty = new DataColumn();
    da.Fill(ds);
    GridView1.DataSourceID = null;

    //New Code Added Here
    DataRow row = ds.NewRow();
    //your columns
    row["columnOne"] = valueofone;
    row["columnTwo"] = valueoftwo;
    dtglb.Rows.Add(row);
        foreach(DataRow dr in dtglb.Rows)
    {
     ds.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
    //=========
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

add rows to DataGridView itself

```
DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
dataGridView1.BeginEdit();
//your columns
row.Cells["columnOne"] = valueofone;
row.Cells["columnTwo"] = valueoftwo;
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
dataGridView1.EndEdit();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.But how can I give values to individual columns.In my code is it possible?pls see my code above.

Comment: @abatishchev:: I tried your code but I am working with webapplication and webcontent form. therefore your methods does not work for me. If any solution exists then please help me.

Comment: @user698273: In fact, that's @Nighil's code, I just minor-edited his post.

Comment: @user698273: a new answer is posted please check it some updation in your code

Comment: @Nighil:: I have tested ur code but the problem remains same.Whenever I am going to click add button secondtime it clears the previous row whitch was inserted last time. any suggestions?

Comment: @Nighil::I applied ur new code but it gives error::This row already belongs to another table.    wat's dat??????

Comment: Hello all the Friends I just got the answer.Please check the code above.